# jQuery datatable row background color not changing in sorted column

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using a jQuery datatable and I would like the background color to change based on a condition hover the row that is sorted does not have my background color as you can see on my image.

[image: image of datatable]

Here is my condition

```
        "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
            if (data.componente.default_ubicacion.ubicacion_id === 0) {
                $(row).css("background-color", "rgb(225, 27, 27, 100%)");
                $(row).css("color", "white");
                $(row).addClass("group");
            }
        },
```

And this is the css that is causing the problem

```
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
        if (data.componente.default_ubicacion.ubicacion_id === 0) {
            $(row).css("background-color", "rgb(225, 27, 27, 100%)");
            $(row).css("color", "white");
            $(row).addClass("yourClassName");
        }
    }
```

And then in your CSS file include this:

```
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.yourClassName.even > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.yourClassName.even > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: transparent;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.yourClassName.odd > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.yourClassName.odd > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Obviously I don't know your data, but I prepared a little example for you:

```js
var oTable = $('#tableName').DataTable({ 
    rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
    if(data[0] == 2){
        $(row).css('background-color', 'rgb(225, 27, 27, 100%)')
            .css('color', 'white')
            .addClass('yourClassName');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.yourClassName.even > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.yourClassName.even > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: transparent;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.yourClassName.odd > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.yourClassName.odd > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="data-table-container">
  <table id="tableName" class="table cell-border order-column stripe">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Beer</th>
        <th>Wine</th>
        <th>Spirits</th>
        <th>Other</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Estonia</td>
        <td>EE</td>
        <td>14.97</td>
        <td>5.87</td>
        <td>1.65</td>
        <td>5.64</td>
        <td>1.81</td>
        <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Belarus</td>
        <td>BY</td>
        <td>14.44</td>
        <td>2.5</td>
        <td>0.75</td>
        <td>6.73</td>
        <td>4.46</td>
        <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```